# How to set text value from `select` drop list into `input` text field?

Tags: javascript, html

I am beginner in `java` and not familiar with `javascript` or `php`, so I just can explore and copypast simplies exemplars of `javascript/php` code for my needs. So that what I did find in stackowerflow and try to implement for my need:

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onchange() {
        var e = document.getElementById("persId");
        var persSelected = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById("myInput").value=persSelected;
    }
</script>
```

**And body:**

```
<body>
<div th:replace="fragments/main.html :: top_menu"/>

<div class="w3-container" align="center">

    <form action="/add" method="post" class="w3-container w3-card-4 w3-light-grey w3-text-blue w3-margin w3-center" style="width: 50%" >
        <h2 class="w3-center">Add the challenger</h2>


        <select name="pers" id="persId" onchange="onchange();">
            <option th:each="person: ${personList}">
                <title id="titleId" th:text="${person.getName()}"/>
            </option>
        </select>

<div class="w3-row w3-section">
    <div class="w3-col" style="width:50px"><i class="w3-xxlarge fa fa-user"></i></div>
    <div class="w3-rest">
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" id="myInput" name="lastName" type="text"  onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for last names.." title="Type in a last name">
    </div>
</div>
```

I get the list of `person` into drop list, but not have the selected item into `input` text field.

**How to correctly implement this code?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are to problems with your code

1. options don't have title elements
2. since there are no title elements you have to get the selected value from the select element

Let me explain.

This code makes no sense:

```
<option th:each="person: ${personList}">
    <title id="titleId" th:text="${person.getName()}"/>
</option>
```

Options don't have titles. Instead you should just use text inside of options.
Like this:

```
<option th:each="person: ${personList}">
    ${person.getName()} // this should just turn into text
</option>
```

so you will end up with:

```
<option th:each="person: ${personList}">
    John Doe
</option>
```

okay first thing done now to fix your other problem. :)

This line could have worked.

```
var persSelected = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

but since there are no element inside the option, then we need to get the value somewhere else.

The easiest way to do so would be to get the value of the select element.

like this:

```
var persSelected = document.getElementById("persId").value;
```

here is an example of a working script file:

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onchange() {
        var persSelected = document.getElementById("persId").value;
        document.getElementById("myInput").value = persSelected;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this line:
document.getElementById("persId").value=persSelected;

Should be:
document.getElementById("myInput").value=persSelected;

Comment: Thank you. I update my question with you recommendation. But I still do not get result

Answer (score 0):

I dont know - how and why are using parameter `type` in `script` block.. But, when I erase this code: `type="text/javascript"` all works well